# Responsive design - stacking 2 divs but the first one goes onto new line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid, media-queries

In a responsive page, I have to stack 2 divs. Simple task, but I'd like the first div to go on to the new line. So it doesn't have to follow the "normal" flow of the page.
Is it possible and how? Any help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responsive grid systems usually use relative positioning along with `float`, or `flexbox`. The `flexbox` approach makes it easier to reverse the order of grid columns...

```
/* smaller - mobile widths */
.container-flex {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.container-flex>div {
   background: #eee;
   width: 100%;
}

/* larger widths */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container-flex {
        flex-direction: row;
    }
    .container-flex>div {
       width: 50%;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/1Je6BkNrjR

Comment: Great, I went for the flexbox solution. Thanks!